# How to remove sub-query for the same, and after that i want same result

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have one query which got result of visitors. Without use of sub-query.

**How can I get last visitor's date in this query**

```
select u.id,
    u.fname,
    u.lname,
    CONCAT_WS(' ',u.fname,u.lname) as fullname,
    u.gender,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, u.bdate, CURDATE()) as age,
    u.username,
    g.profile_image,
    v.userid,
    v.visitor_id,
    v.visited_time 
    from tbl_user u 
    inner join (
        select * from tbl_visitors order by visited_time desc 
    )as v on(v.visitor_id=u.id) 
    left join tbl_gallery_master g on(u.profile_image=g.id) 
    group by v.userid,v.visitor_id 
    order by v.visited_time desc
```

in this query I got absolutely fine records, but **I don't want subquery**.

Comment: No need to write sub query just join the table as you are using inner join that with fetch conman records between two table

Comment: Hello Ashish, thank for suggestions but i want last date for visiters, using this i only get first record because group by only take first record in this era. i want last record in group by using this

Comment: Does this query even work? you'll need to use aggregate functions like `MAX`, `MIN` to work with `group by`. All table `u` and `g` columns should not work. At least not in SQL server

Comment: which database is it?

Answer (score 0):

```html
select u.id,u.fname,u.lname,CONCAT_WS(' ',u.fname,u.lname) as fullname,
   u.gender,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, u.bdate, CURDATE()) as age,
   u.username,g.profile_image,v.userid,v.visitor_id,v.visited_time 
from tbl_user u 
inner join tbl_visitors as v  on(v.visitor_id=u.id) 
left join tbl_gallery_master g on(u.profile_image=g.id) 
group by v.userid,v.visitor_id 
order by v.visited_time desc
```

Comment: Thank for replay, but this not get correct data. my purpose of query is only last visited time i will required and this query not return last datetime

Answer (score 0):

If your query works than this should work also:

```
select u.id,
u.fname,
u.lname,
CONCAT_WS(' ',u.fname,u.lname) as fullname,
u.gender,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, u.bdate, CURDATE()) as age,
u.username,
g.profile_image,
v.userid,
v.visitor_id,
v.visited_time 
from tbl_user u 
inner join  tbl_visitors v on v.visitor_id=u.id
left join tbl_gallery_master g on u.profile_image=g.id 
group by v.userid, v.visitor_id 
order by v.visited_time desc
```